# Why is a observer class not working in model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a `Base` model that I used to extend in all other Models. I created an `observer` for it called `BaseObserver` and registered it at `boot` method of `EventServiceProvider`. I have a `creating` event and would like to put my logic there every time I create a new other `Model`.

The problem is that the `creating` method in `BaseObserver` is not being called. But, when I created a closure for `creating` in `Base` model, it worked. What seems to be the problem here?

Base.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Base extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    // This closure will work but If I commented this out, BaseObserver's creating method won't work
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function ($base) {
            dd('hellp from base model');
        });
    }
}
```

BaseObserver.php

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Base;

class BaseObserver
{
    public function creating(Base $base)
    {
        dd('hello from base obserer');

        $base->created_by = auth()->user()?->_id;
    }

    public function updating(Base $base)
    {
        dd('hello from base obserer');
        
        $base->updated_by = auth()->user()?->_id;
    }
}
```

EventServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Base;
use App\Observers\BaseObserver;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        Base::observe(BaseObserver::class);
    }

    public function shouldDiscoverEvents()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Team.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Base;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Team extends Base
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'leader_id',
        'member_ids',
    ];
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: You must bind the observer to a particular model and not the BaseModel. When you extend the Base model class with the booted method, the observers are registered on each class that extend the Base model. Whereas when you observe on the `Base` model with `Base::observe(BaseObserver::class);`, the observers are registered for  `static::registerModelEvent($event, 'App\Models\Base@'.$event);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has to work

```
class Base extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::observe(BaseObserver::class);
    }
}
```